# Is there a way to fix the enter and delete keys in [Console]::ReadKey() in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a script here:

```
Clear-Host
$Word = [String]::Empty
$Mode = "INSERT MODE"
While ($True) {
    $E = [Console]::ReadKey($True)
    If ($E.Key -eq "Escape") {
        Break
    }
    If ($E.Key -eq "Enter") {
        Write-Host `n
        $Word += "`n"
    }Else {
        $Word += $E.KeyChar
        Write-Host $E.KeyChar -NoNewLine
    }
}
Clear-Host
Return $Word
```

It is supposed to read the user's keypresses and then print them out onto the screen, and it works fine apart from the backspace and enter keys. Enter prints two newlines and backspace moves the pointer backwards and just overwrites the character like this:

```
Hello worle_ (Spelling Error)
Hello worle̲ (Pressed backspace)
Hello world_ (Just overwrote the letter as if it wasn't there)
```

How can  I get enter to print one newline and properly use backspaces?
I'm on powershell 5.1 and using windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$word = ''
$mode = 'INSERT MODE'
$done = $false
While (-not $done) {
    $e = [Console]::ReadKey($true)
    switch ($e.Key) {
      'Escape' { $done = $true; break }
      'Enter' {  $word += "`n"; Write-Host; break }
      'Backspace' { 
        if ($word.Length) { $word = $word.Substring(0, $word.Length-1) } 
        Write-Host -NoNewLine "`b `b"
        break 
      }
      default {  $word += $e.KeyChar; Write-Host -NoNewLine $e.KeyChar }
    }
}

Write-Host

# Output the captured input.
"[$word]"
```

- To emit just a single newline, simply use `Write-Host` *without arguments*.
- To emulate interactive backspace behavior, emit a backspace, then a space, followed by another backspace.

  - By default, emitting a backspace character to the console is *non-destructive*: that is, the cursor moves one position back, but *doesn't erase* the character at the previous cursor position.
  - The technique above makes it *appear* as if the character was erased, by replacing it with a *space*.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest leveraging the .NET assembly "System.Windows.Forms".

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("Hello")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("World")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{Enter}")
```

You can find other special characters [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: How exactly would that be implemented? I've tied several ways which all end in the enter key not working, and I can't exactly see what you mean

Comment: While this may work in principle, sending keystrokes is invariably brittle, and there's no need for it here.